# Reading csv file columns and writing them to a new file

Tags: php, csv

I've been trying to read a csv file and extract the first two columns and save it into another csv file.

The csv file is tab separated. The code is written do show it on the webpage but when it comes to writing the csv file. It prints on a new line which I don't want. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or what should I add to get the output in one line per row?

```
$string = <<<CSV
"IRC_01T_00K_002"   "Bonjour monsieur, je m'appelle Léon Bop j'habite au Sénégal, j'ai 28ans. J'étais religieux moine bénédictin et je viens de quitter la vie religieuse il y a 2ans. J'ai fait l'hôtellerie comme la plonge, la sécurité et équipier de cuisine, actuellement je suis commerçant, et depuis quelques temps je cherche un correspondant canadien pour venir immigrer au Canada, puisque c'est mon pays de rêve.\
Voilà mes coordonnées:\
leonbop@gmail.com\
+221775797837." "Wrong Channel"     "2018-10-26 13:57:16"   "DE8B33B0-C68F-11E8-8BFB-0242AC110004"  "2018-10-26 13:57:16"   "DE8B33B0-C68F-11E8-8BFB-0242AC110004"
"IRC_01T_00K_002"   "bonjour le Canadian immigration je suis au Congo je suis un chauffeur" "Wrong Channel"     "2018-10-12 15:53:29"   "DE8B33B0-C68F-11E8-8BFB-0242AC110004"  "2018-10-12 15:53:29"   "DE8B33B0-C68F-11E8-8BFB-0242AC110004"
"IRC_031_000_008"   "Thnks so much.  I will apply before her status expires.  You guys are so helpful \
 . I am lucky that I am in canada in people like you ." "Chat Conclusion"       "2018-10-24 17:41:50"   "380922FF-AB0E-11E8-80D2-0242AC110004"  "2018-10-24 17:41:50"   "380922FF-AB0E-11E8-80D2-0242AC110004"
"IRC_031_000_008"   "Ok thanks a lot"   "Chat Conclusion"       "2018-10-19 04:19:35"   "A4D460D3-F448-1693-BA91-C6A0A40998BB"  "2018-10-19 04:19:35"   "A4D460D3-F448-1693-BA91-C6A0A40998BB"
CSV;

//$string = str_replace(array('\\','/','\\\\','*','"','<','>','|',"'"), '', $string);

$fp=fopen('test13.csv','w');
$handle = fopen("data://text/plain," . $string, "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        //$num = count($data);
        for ($c=0; $c < 2; $c++) 
        {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            $data[$c] = str_replace(array('\\','/','\\\\','*','"','<','>','|',"'"), '', $data[$c]);
            $data[$c] = preg_replace('/^\h*\v+/m', '', $data[$c]); // remove empty lines
            $data[$c] = trim($data[$c]);
            fwrite($fp,$data[$c]);
            fwrite($fp,"\t");
        //fwrite($fp, $data[$c]);

        }
    fwrite($fp,"\n");
    }
    fclose($fp);
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Output:

```
IRC_01T_00K_002 Bonjour monsieur, je mappelle Léon Bop jhabite au Sénégal, jai 28ans. Jétais religieux moine bénédictin et je viens de quitter la vie religieuse il y a 2ans. Jai fait lhôtellerie comme la plonge, la sécurité et équipier de cuisine, actuellement je suis commerçant, et depuis quelques temps je cherche un correspondant canadien pour venir immigrer au Canada, puisque cest mon pays de rêve.
Voilà mes coordonnées:
leonbop@gmail.com
 221775797837.
```

I expect the output to be: `"first column" \t "second column"`. The new csv file created should have two columns and the second column value should be in one single line rather than multiple lines.

Comment: You have newlines in the second column in the CSV file. They're being copied to the result.

Answer (score 0):

You have newlines in the second column of the CSV file. You can replace them with spaces:

```
data[$c] = str_replace("\n", " ", $data[$c]);
```

Comment: The output is still in printing in new lines @Barmar.